# Magento 2: How to pass IN/OR Condition in Query

Tags: magento2, database, query

I have below query

```
$customers = array(1,2);

$select = $connection->select()
->from(
        ['ce' => 'customer_entity'], ['entity_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email'] // Select Only Required Fields
)
->where('ce.entity_id IN? ',$customers);
echo $select;
exit;
```

How to pass IN & OR condition?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to modify your where slightly. Replace:

```
->where('ce.entity_id IN? ',$customers);
```

With:

```
->where('ce.entity_id IN (?)', $customers);
```

Comment: Thanks @Raphael again. Do we any link for this where we can find all conditions with Match. Support for OR/And condition what to do?

Comment: @AnkitShah I don't understand what you're asking. Using IN is always an OR condition. You can't do an AND condition on a primary key.

Comment: Hi @Raphael Ashish has given answer `orWhere` / `andWhere`

Answer (score 2):

FOR OR condition you can use :

```
->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("(CONDITION_1 OR (CONDITION_2 AND (CONDITION_3 OR CONDITION_4)))"));
```

OR you can use

```
->orWhere instead of ->where
```